# Excel compare two columns if equal gain results

Tags: excel, validation, filter, excel-formula, compare

I have trouble get a formula done in Excel document. Hope you can give me a hand.  See this image so I can explain to you better:

[image]

I need the names and the numbers which are in the first sheet to be compared with the same color columns in second sheet. If there are matches in one of the data (names or numbers) the green result in the second sheet to be transferred in the Z column of the first sheet.

PS: it will be very nice if I can get different colors of z column for 1 match and for 2 matches.

Hope you understand me, sorry for any bad English.

Comment: Sounds like `INDEX/MATCH` is what you need. What happens if the name matches for one row in sheet 2 and the number matches a different one?

Comment: It is imposible for that. But it can give us some error or coloring the cell in red. Can  you give me link or some advice how to make what I want to work. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that by "It is impossible for that" you mean "It is impossible for both values in any given row to match their respective columns in the table on Sheet2."

Try putting this formula in cell `Z1` and populate down:

```
=CONCATENATE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I1,Sheet2!B$1:C$5,2,FALSE),""),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(M1,Sheet2!A$1:C$5,3,FALSE),""))
```

Comment: `=IFERROR(INDEX([fb.xlsx]fbsheet!$D$1:[fb.xlsx]fbsheet!$D$200; MATCH(I184; [fb.xlsx]fbsheet!$C$1:[fb.xlsx]fbsheet!$C$200; 0);0);"")`

I came up with that and it works just fine. Now there are 2 columns for name and number separated. I can compare if first is equal to second to be colored green and  it will give the result I wanted. Now I seek software for facebook bulk messages. U have any idea ? We are post office and we want to message our clients when they have package.